# How could I add another current object like current user in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have PHP system works good and our team start to integrate it with Laravel Framework, and we did, but actually our system build everything on the session for example If I need my current organization it exists on a session and current user and current module also exist on the session, so these currents data sometimes gives me wrong stored data if user open more than one tap on the browser, and also class session reach to the capacity of the accepted digits because of our system store in the session huge of data.

So my questions:

- what is an alternative for us to store currents data instead of a session, is there a way or something like this?
- if its, we know in Laravel the current user represent like as `Auth::user()` so how could I make current organization as `Organization::id()` and current module as `ModuleA::id()` and so on.

I will be thankful if you answered the two questions, even if you give me a suggestion it will be good also.

Comment: If you elaborate more on the process of how one currently switches between organizations, it may help us find an answer that will work for you. Currently I am unsure about: what you are using the Organization for and how a User would go about changing their current "working" organization.

Comment: thank you @Sawyer, I am using the current Organization to query for some data like getting ` [jobs, vacant, jobunit]` and our system is legacy we can't avoid Organization if we did it will be made a bug in somewhere in our system